# Failed to receive system gesture state notification before the next touch

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am currently using touch methods on 2 buttons, that are `SKSpriteNodes`. I am receiving and gesture state failure but I'm not sure why because I am not using gestures, I am using `touchBegan` and `touchEnded` for touch controls.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let pointTouched = touch.location(in: self)
        if leftArrow.contains(pointTouched) {
            moveWizard(moveBy: -60, forTheKey: "left")
            wizardRunAnimation(forTheKey: "wizardRun")
            wizardNode.xScale = -1
        }
        if rightArrow.contains(pointTouched) {
            moveWizard(moveBy: 60, forTheKey: "right")
            wizardRunAnimation(forTheKey: "wizardRun")
            wizardNode.xScale = 1
        }
        if attackButton.contains(pointTouched) {
            wizardAttackAnimation()
        }
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    wizardNode.removeAction(forKey: "left")
    wizardNode.removeAction(forKey: "right")
    wizardNode.removeAction(forKey: "wizardRun")
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Have you tried setting breakpoints to see which line causes it to fail?

Comment: @Michael When I run the app on my phone when I tap the button and he wont move, but the xScale works, and I get this message in my console "Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch" but it does not crash. When I run the simulator he moves and I don't get this message.

Comment: @Michael it doesn't crash

Comment: did you try cleaning the build?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yeah, now he doesnt move on either